# Brightness not working on Samsung N150 (netbook)

Tags: debian, brightness

I have problems with managing the brightness on my netbook Samsung. I created and edited the 20.intel.conf file but nothing happened.
I've also checked the graphics in /sys/class/backlight, and it lists these:

intel_backlight  samsung

I've also installed xbacklight and it seems to work properly.But I heard that only changes the color of the screen not the brightness.Is it true or not?

Help is appreciated.

Thanks.